# Getting an invalid syntax error in Vs Code on the first "or"

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, syntax, syntax-error

I really cant figure out what's the problem here.

```
def winner(board, letter):
#below is the winning combination. If any of the combination matches the winner is gonna be declared
    (board['top-L'] == letter and board['top-M'] == letter and board['top-R'] == letter) **or**
    (board['low-L'] == letter and board['low-M'] == letter and board['low-R'] == letter) or
    (board['mid-L'] == letter and board['mid-M'] == letter and board['mid-R'] == letter) or
    (board['top-L'] == letter and board['mid-L'] == letter and board['low-L'] == letter) or
    (board['top-M'] == letter and board['mid-M'] == letter and board['low-M'] == letter) or
    (board['top-R'] == letter and board['mid-R'] == letter and board['low-R'] == letter) or
    (board['top-L'] == letter and board['mid-M'] == letter and board['low-R'] == letter) or
    (board['top-R'] == letter and board['mid-M'] == letter and board['low-L'] == letter) or
```

Comment: You can't  break up a line like taht in Python.

Comment: So all of them have to be on the same line?

Comment: The code you have makes no sense.  You have a long and complicated expression, but never use its result.

Comment: No, there are various ways to break up a long line

Comment: Look up "line continuation"